# Prevent VS Code from auto completing HTML

Tags: html, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

I saw some similar questions but none of them solve my problem.

Whenever I edit an HTML tag, VS Code always selects what it thinks is the matching tag and edits it along with what I am typing. This is very annoying because it often changes the incorrect tags. I want to completely disable this. I do not want anything else in the file to be modified when I am changing an HTML tag. I have diabled `HTML > Format` and `HTML: Auto Closing Tags` but it still automatically changes other tags when I want to do it manually. Is there any other setting that will completely prevent any auto changes in HTML?

Settings
[image]

Incorrect tag being automatically selected and changed
[image]

settings.json

```
{
    "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
    "telemetry.enableCrashReporter": false,
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
    "python.formatting.formatOnSave": false,
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "workbench.tree.indent": 16,
    "html.format.enable": false,
    "typescript.autoClosingTags": false,
    "javascript.autoClosingTags": false,
    "html.autoClosingTags": false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add the following setting:
`"html.mirrorCursorOnMatchingTag": false`

[The setting documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_mirror-cursor)

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using VSCode and am not experiencing these issues, it's strange that it's still doing it even after disabling the setting.

Can you please follow these instructions and post your `settings.json` file? (this is the underlying file that vscode uses to define it's settings)

### Settings file locations (from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

> By default VS Code shows the Settings editor, but you can still edit the underlying settings.json file by using the Open Settings (JSON) command or by changing your default settings editor with the workbench.settings.editor setting.
>
> Depending on your platform, the user settings file is located here:
>
> **Windows** %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
>
> **macOS** $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json
>
> **Linux** $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json

There should be a line similar to:

```
    "html.autoClosingTags": true,
```

OR

```
    "html.mirrorCursorOnMatchingTag": true,
```

If you change this to false it may fix the problem but if you show your config file we should be able to see if there is another issue.

Comment: In settings.json, the html.autoClosingTags is already false.

Comment: I don't think that is the correct setting, I notice that when it is true, it will auto add a closing tag but it will not when it is false. That seems to be a different setting than what is causing the auto-select-and-edit of "matching" tags.

Comment: Can you try adding `"javascript.autoClosingTags": false`? Nevermind - saw that you've already got this line in your settings.json

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: Yes, I have a few extensions. The most relevant ones would be HTML CSS Support, and Bracket Pair Colorizer 2

Comment: Can you please disable all of your extensions and see if the problem goes away? I have a feeling it may be one of them doing this.

Comment: Okay, I will try that.

Comment: Thank you, let me know how you go. It may be a process of elimination turning them back on individually until you find the offending extension.

Comment: This did not solve the problem, I disabled all extensions, restarted it and still having the problem.

Comment: I found the solution! Thanks for your effort!

Comment: It's very strange, it looks like this feature is enabled but it's doing it without you pressing F2: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41#_html-rename-tags

Can you tell me your vscode version? Mine is 1.41.1

Comment: Mine is the same version

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_mirror-cursor

Comment: Ah I was JUST about to tell you to try `html.mirrorCursorOnMatchingTag` :( No worries

Comment: No worries, I have edited my original answer to include the solution that you found. Not sure if you want to mark it as the answer but it might be helpful for anyone with a similar problem so they can find out how to edit their `settings.json` file. Thanks again :)